# Anomaly in GNU Prolog `delete/3` predicate?

Tags: prolog

I found an inconsistency in behavior in the GNU Prolog (version 1.4.2) `delete/3` predicate:

```
| ?- delete([a,b,c], b, R).

R = [a,c]

yes
| ?- delete([(a,_), (b,_), (c,_)], (b,_), R).

R = [(a,_),(b,_),(c,_)]

yes
| ?- member( (b,_), [(a,_), (b,_), (c,_)] ).

true ? ;

no
| ?- select((b,_), [(a,_), (b,_), (c,_)], R).

R = [(a,_),(c,_)] ? ;

no
| ?-
```

All of the above results I expected, except for that of, `delete([(a,_), (b,_), (c,_)], (b,_), R).`. If you run the same set of queries in SWI Prolog, for example, the `delete([(a,_), (b,_), (c,_)], (b,_), R).` yields, `R = [(a,_), (c,_)]` as I would expect.

My question is whether this is expected based upon some specific "interpretation" of the `delete/3` predicate, or is it perhaps a bug in GNU Prolog?

Comment: The semantics of `delete/3` varies across Prolog systems.

Comment: the [doc](http://gprolog.univ-paris1.fr/manual/html_node/gprolog044.html#sec213) states that 'A strict term equality is required'

Comment: @CapelliC thanks for spotting that. I hadn't noticed it. I just got used to using `delete/3` a certain way in SWI and GNU and lulled myself into implicitly expecting it to behave the same.

Comment: @l'L'l yes, I agree and understand the doc states "GNU Prolog predicate". I just didn't expect the given behavior. So it is not a bug. Just the way it works.

Comment: See the [documentation of delete/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=delete/3) in SWI-Prolog: "**deprecated** There are too many ways in which one might want to delete elements from a list to justify the name. Think of matching (`=` vs. `==`), delete first/all, be deterministic or not."

Comment: @CapelliC it's interesting that the very next line in the [GNU manual for delete/3 and `select/3`](http://gprolog.univ-paris1.fr/manual/html_node/gprolog044.html#sec213), when describing `select/3` by comparison, doesn't say anything regarding the type of term matching used, which might leave the reader to assume that strict equality might also be used for `select/3`, although it is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name `delete` is terribly non-descriptive. Does it mean deleting all **equal** elements or all **matching** elements? If the later, does the unification between the element we're deleting and an element of the list carries when moving to the next list element or is undone?

From your trace above, in particular the second query, it seems that `delete/3` is using equality instead of unification (as, as you know, each occurrence of an anonymous variable is a different variable). The documentation confirms it:

http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#sec213

There's really no bug as there's no consensus on a unique semantics for a `delete/3`predicate. At most, there's a consensus that's a bad name for a library predicate. Just a predicate name that should be avoided in any Prolog library. That said, compatibility with old code often results in its presence.

Comment: Thanks Paulo. I agree about the name. It is, in fact, so generic that it's part of what made me think it would have consistent behavior (if that makes sense). I guess if I had read a bit more carefully, I would have spotted the caveats. I guess I expected it to be consistent with `select/3` (*i.e.*, "just like `select/3` except it removes all occurrences instead of just one).