# Compatibility of different clp(FD) library implementations

Tags: prolog, compatibility, clpfd

Is there some place I can find a collection of differences in clpfd implementations?

Comment: GNU Prolog is even more different than either of those. In GNU, they use a variety of `fd_...` predicates, such as `fd_domain`, to specify a domain.

Comment: I agree. I have the same feeling about [inconsistency in the `delete/3` predicate implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29289228/anomaly-in-gnu-prolog-delete-3-predicate).

Comment: `X in {1}\/(3..5)\/{7}.` works in SWI. So there is a certain level of compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is kind of a list of languages that support one
form or another of constraint logic programming. This
is sometimes denoted as CLP(*):

See section "Logic programming based constraint logic":
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming#Some_languages_that_support_constraint_programming

Whether all of the languages on the list also support
CLP(FD) I am not sure. The wiki page also doesn't make
a comparison matrice. But it could be a start to look into
different systems.

There are many interesting dimensions of CLP(FD) systems:
- are bignums supported: GNU No, SWI-Prolog Yes, Jekejeke Yes
- are negative integers supported: GNU No, SWI-Prolog Yes, Jekejeke Yes
- what arithmetic expressions are allowed: t.b.d.
- what set notations are allowed: GNU limited, SWI-Prolog sup/inf, Jekejeke sup/inf
- is reification supported: GNU Yes, SWI-Prolog Yes, Jekejeke Not Yet
- what special constraints are supported: GNU cardinality, SWi-Prolog cardinality and others, Jekejeke Not Yet
- what are the labeling parameters: t.b.d.

Bye